# Combinations of 8 bits binary in an two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, binary, bit

I wonder how to put all combinations of 8 bits binary numbers into a two-dimensional array in C programming.
256x8 sized array and all combinations of 0 and 1 should be filled in the array.

From 00000000 to 11111111

Comment: What kind of combination do you mean? And do you mean you want a 256x256 sized array, or something else? Please clarify question!

Comment: 256x8 sized array and all combinations of 0 and 1 should be filled in the array.

Comment: for loop from 0 to 255 with the y-step for 2d array of 8...

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to enumerate all possibilities, you can simply use the binary value of your index. Here is a version with an unrolled loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    t[i][0] = (i >> 7) & 1;
    t[i][1] = (i >> 6) & 1;
    t[i][2] = (i >> 5) & 1;
    t[i][3] = (i >> 4) & 1;
    t[i][4] = (i >> 3) & 1;
    t[i][5] = (i >> 2) & 1;
    t[i][6] = (i >> 1) & 1;
    t[i][7] = (i >> 0) & 1;
}
```

Where `t` is your result array and `i` a loop index.

The statement `t[i][5] = (i >> 2) & 1;` (for instance) works as follow:

- `i >> 2` puts the 3<sup>e</sup> bit of `i` at the 1<sup>e</sup> position;
- `(i >> 2) & 1` let us know if the 3<sup>e</sup> bit of `i` is either `0` or `1`.

**Example<sub>1</sub>**:

- Input: `00001111`;
- `i >> 2`: `00000011`;
- `(i >> 2) & 1`: `00000001`

**Example<sub>2</sub>**:

- Input: `00001011`;
- `i >> 2`: `00000010`;
- `(i >> 2) & 1`: `00000000`

Note we can also use a macro to improve readability:

```
/* Get the value of the bit at position `n` of `x`. */
#define GET_BIT(x, n) (((x) >> (n)) & 1)

for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    t[i][0] = GET_BIT(i, 7);
    t[i][1] = GET_BIT(i, 6);
    t[i][2] = GET_BIT(i, 5);
    t[i][3] = GET_BIT(i, 4);
    t[i][4] = GET_BIT(i, 3);
    t[i][5] = GET_BIT(i, 2);
    t[i][6] = GET_BIT(i, 1);
    t[i][7] = GET_BIT(i, 0);
}
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Get the value of the bit at position `n` of `x`. */
#define GET_BIT(x, n) (((x) >> (n)) & 1)

int main(void)
{
    int t[256][8], i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        t[i][0] = GET_BIT(i, 7);
        t[i][1] = GET_BIT(i, 6);
        t[i][2] = GET_BIT(i, 5);
        t[i][3] = GET_BIT(i, 4);
        t[i][4] = GET_BIT(i, 3);
        t[i][5] = GET_BIT(i, 2);
        t[i][6] = GET_BIT(i, 1);
        t[i][7] = GET_BIT(i, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i, puts(""))
        for (j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            printf("%d", t[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what [ (i >> 7) & 1 ] does

Comment: It gives the value of the 8e bit of `i`: `0` or `1`.

Comment: if iam not thinking wrong will t[i][0] = 1 and t[i][1] = 1 ?

Comment: It depends on the value of `i`. See the test in my edit.

Comment: Could you please explain what happens if i=8. And use this (i >> 2) & 1

Comment: If `8` in binary is `1000`. `(1000 >> 2) == 0010` and `(1000 >> 2) & 1 == 0000`. So it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is to get you started:

```
for(int i=0;i<256;++i) {
    a[0]=i&(1<<0);
    a[1]=i&(1<<1);
    a[2]=i&(1<<2);
    ...
    a[7]=i&(1<<7);
}
```

The reason why this will result in all combinations is, that when `i=0...255` then it will go through all the combinations 00000000...11111111 just in bits, not bytes: so all you have to do is extract the bits into bytes.

Comment: I want it to be something like this:
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
00000101

Comment: yes, it will be. for example consider what happens when i=3: the bit-representation of 3 is 00000011. so you only have to extract the bits into bytes by using the `&` (binary and) with a specially shifted "extractor bit" (1<<0 and 1<<1 in this case).